# Redefining a fuction used to define this function in Scheme

Tags: function, scheme, racket, redefinition

I think the title is a bit weird but, for example, is there a way to redefine the addition in Scheme so that (+ arg1 arg2) gives arg1 + arg2 + 1?

I can create a new function @:

`(define @ (lambda args (+ (apply + args) 1)))`

such that (@ 42 13) gives (42 + 13 + 1). But is there a way to do something which would look like:

`(define + (lambda args (+ (apply + args) 1)))`

but of course without the error since, here, it says that + is undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R7RS version of Scheme we have imports so here we can do it:

```
#!r7rs

(import (except (scheme base) +)
        (rename (scheme base) (+ base:+)))

(define (+ . args)
  (apply base:+ 1 args))

(+ 1 1) ; ==> 3
```

In R6RS version its the same except `(scheme base)` is `(rnrs base)`
Racket has something very similar:

```
#lang racket

(require (only-in racket/base [+ base:+]))
    
(define (+ . args)
  (apply base:+ 1 args))

(+ 1 1) ; ==> 3
```

In R5RS report Scheme and older the report allows a user to redefine a procedure to extend the features of it, but it is a violation that it for the defined types would result in different results than the original scheme report version would. Thus redefining `+` like this is a violation and not portable Scheme. It might work in some implementation, but the wording is done such that a smart Scheme compiler can do constant folding and expect the correct result from supported types.

```
#!r5rs

(define + 
  (let ((r5rs:+ +))
    (lambda args
      (apply r5rs:+ 1 args))))

(+ 1 1) ; ==> 2 or 3, perhaps an error
```